# jQuery cropit plugin check if current image is zoomable

Tags: jquery, crop

I use this plugin to crop images: http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/

I want to know how to find out if the current image is zoomable so I can hide the zoom div if not, it says this function is for it: `$imageCropper.cropit('isZoomable');` But how t use it? I'm a beginner in jQuery.
This is my code so far:

```
    $(function() {
        $('.image-editor').cropit({ imageBackground: true, imageBackgroundBorderWidth: 15 });

if ($('.image-editor').cropit('isZoomable')) { 
            alert("you can zoom");
        } // EDIT: I added it but it's not working

            $('form').submit(function() {
                // Move cropped image data to hidden input
                var imageData = $('.image-editor').cropit('export', {
                                                            type: 'image/jpeg',
                                                            quality: .9
                                                            });
                $('.hidden-image-data').val(imageData);

                // Print HTTP request params
                var formValue = $(this).serialize();

                $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'doupload.php',
                data: {bilddata: formValue},
                success: function(data) {

                }
               });
                return false;
            });
        })
```

Comment: So I deleted my answer. Good luck with this :)

Comment: Why did you do that? I solved it, your code works onchange at image input, write your answer again and i'll accept it, and thanks :D

Comment: Thanks "undelete" button hahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just like this:

```
if ($('.image-editor').cropit('isZoomable')) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work, pls check my edit, is it the right place for it?

Comment: Is it throwing an error in the console? Do you want to check it before the submit?

Comment: Write `console.log($('.image-editor').cropit('isZoomable'))` before the `if` and see in the console if it prints "true" or "false"

Comment: It prints null on pageload and then just nothing after i select/change images